# How to write a function which will redirect the user to another URL? (FLASK)

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I want to write a function that will redirect the user to another URL. [Here's the project link](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/web-invoicer/blob/main/app.py). On the `Submit` button click, there will be a number of functions running one after another. It looks like this:

Button Click -> Get Values from the form -> Pass these values to the export_PDF() function -> redirect user to another URL (which contains newly generated PDF file)

Because of that, this process of redirection needs to happen on a function call, at a specific moment (at the end).

Comment: ...the [redirect](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect function.

Documentation Link: [redirects-and-errors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors)

Comment: I tried:

       @app.route("/")
       def starting_url():
            return redirect("/download")

but the redirect doesn't happen. What am I missing?